# In WordPress, insert custom field data into file instead of database

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Is there a way to insert data from a WordPress custom field into a custom file instead of into the MySQL database?

The reason I want to do this is because I am trying to set up a custom field as a sort of PHP sandbox for the user and I would like to just use `include filename.php` in a template file and avoid inserting PHP data into the database and the security vulnerabilities that come along with this, or worse having to use `eval` after the data has been retrieved from the database.

I'm open to any other suggestions to accomplish this, but I think the easiest would be to store the data in a random php file and circumvent the database altogether.

Comment: And you think putting user entered PHP into a file on the server isn't  a security vulnerability...?

Comment: That's a good point, I suppose it's a bad idea all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me preface this by saying:

### this is a bad idea

Your idea is to have end users upload PHP scripts that you will then execute on your server. Whats to stop an attacker from uploading a script like this:

```
<?php
// get a list of all of the wp-config.php files available to this user
$configs = shell_exec("cd ~ && find `pwd` -name wp-config.php");
// go through every match and email the contents 
// of the file to my super secret hacker email or whatever
// btw i now have mysql credentials for all of your wp sites.
?>
```

And that isn't even imaginative.

### that said here is how to do it

#### Download and install https://github.com/fyaconiello/WP_Bad_Idea as a plugin on your WP site

Then add this to your theme's `single-attack_post.php`

```
<h3>THE CODE</h3>
<pre>
<?php include($post->attack_code); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you, I may end up not doing this it seems like there's no way around the potential for evil.